# How to use Airflow to SSH into a server with RSA public/private keys?

Tags: python, ssh, rsa, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a Logstash server I need to run commands in through Cloud Composer which uses Airflow. I am using the SH Operator. I have made the SSH connection and added my RSA Private Key to the extras field. I've tried to connect while having a username entered and while not having a username entered. Everytime, after connecting, I get the error: "Error: SSH Operator Error: No authentication methods available." I can use this RSA key to connect through Putty. I can PING the server as well. There is no  password for this server - only the keys. 
SSHOperator Code:

```
t1 =SSHOperator(
                task_id = 'SSHOperator',

                ssh_hook=sshHook,
                do_xcom_push=True,
                command='ls /logstash/scripts',
                dag=dag
            )
```

SSH Connection:
[ssh connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq2Pl.png)

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly propagate **Extra** field parameters within [Connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-the-ui) definition approaching [SSHOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator) connection type, you should explicitly set the path to your RSA key file in JSON data format, as shared in Airflow [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/ssh.html#ssh-connection), for instance:

```
{
   "key_file": "/PATH_TO_YOUR_KEY/.ssh/KEY_NAME_rsa"
}
```

Comment: that was already set up as I said in my post. The solution to this issue was found to be that the RSA key we had been provided had been generated on a WIndows machine and the VMs are Linux. To fix the issue, we logged into the Clusters associated with the Composer environment and generated keys from there.